# check whether the next row is a duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

How can I check whether the next row is a duplicate one. if duplicate it will move to the next row.

Example:

```
1st row: 1900
2nd row: 1900
3rd row: 2000
```

How can mysql and php can do these results:

```
1st row: 1900
2nd row: 2000
3rd row: 1900
```

Is this possible or any possible codes?

```
<?php
$array   =  array(1900,1900,2000);

$checkDuplicates = array_diff($array);

print_r($checkDuplicates);

?>
```

The next thing how can i move the duplicate row?

Comment: Please provide the code you currently have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store last row in temporary variable $last and in foreach loop do this:

```
$last = '';
foreach ($array as $row){
    if ($row== $last){
        continue;
    } else {
        $returnArray[] = $row;
    }
    $last = $row;
}
var_dump($returnArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You need to stack a second array with unique values.**

```
<?php
$array   =  array(1900,1900,2000);
$array2  =  array();

foreach ($array as $val) {
    if (!in_array($val, $array2)) {
        $array2[] = $val;
    }
}

print_r($array2);
```

**See codepad: http://codepad.org/X8jtnEkq**

If you want to **duplicates appended to the end of the array**, after the script above, use `array_merge($array2, $array);`:

```
<?php
$array   =  array(1900,1900,2000);
$array2  =  array();

foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    if (!in_array($val, $array2)) {
        $array2[] = $val;
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
$array = array_merge($array2, $array);
print_r($array);
```

**Demo http://codepad.org/tRC6P2Go**

Comment: hi dan, how about the duplicate number? it displays Array ( [0] => 1900 [1] => 2000 ). i want is the duplicate will be included also and will be move to the third iteration like this example: Array ( [0] => 1900 [1] => 2000 [2] => 1900 )

Comment: @EdmarCruz but my example will move ALL duplicates, not only next row. If you want ONLY next row, combine mine and Adam's solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [array_unique](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to get unique results and then do an [array_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) between the initial and the uniquified array to get the ids that are doubled to use them for a sql-query to tidy that table:

```
$uniquified = array_unique($initalResults);
$diff = array_diff($initalResults, $uniquified);
```

Comment: Just noticed, that you want to achieve something different

Answer (score 1):

you can use array_unique

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

to extract unique records and then array_diff to extract duplicate records

Comment: OP wants: How can I check whether the **next** row is a duplicate one. Only NEXT

Answer (score 0):

This problem is elementary programming, you would normally have a problem like this in the first week of uni.

array_diff won't help you, it compares two different arrays, whereas you're looking for comparison of the previous element within an array.

The same principle applies whether it is coming from mysql or an array.

Also, ask yourself the question, does this data need to be sorted first ?

Try this

```
<?php

$my_array = array(1900,1900,2000);

$tmp = null ;

for( $i = 0 ; $i<count($my_array) ; $i++) {
    if( $my_array[$i] != $tmp ){
        echo "\nValue $i is different to the last one, 
              should I do extra stuff here ?";
    } else {
        echo "\nValue $i is the same as the last one and equals $tmp";
    }
    $tmp = $my_array[$i] ; 

}


?>
```

The output of the above code is..

```
Value 0 is different to the last one, should I do extra stuff here ?
Value 1 is the same as the last one and equals 1900
Value 2 is different to the last one, should I do extra stuff here ?
```

Determining whether the action is occurring on the first entry is a simple matter of checking the value of $i